# Is voting on taxes ethical without being presented the "numbers"?

Tags: ethics, skepticism

if I base my vote (on taxes) based on republican or democrat anecdote, as well as my own paycheck, is it the right thing for for me to do, to vote on taxes? I am trying to skeptically look at voting (specifically on taxes) ethically. 
..I have been trying to ask this question on google but haven't found anything philosophically related. Starting points would be helpful!

To go more in depth..here are the numbers that I know [below] - I do not know how well the programs I pay for actually work with how much I already pay forward. (ex: does health & human services need more money because it is short staffed, etc...)

State of CA
Budget Item %   Your Contribution
General Government  5.92    $236.21
Health & Human Services 31.94   $1274.41
Education   36.38   $1451.56
Transportation  7.38    $294.46
Public Safety & Criminal Justice    7.44    $296.86
Parks, Environment & Natural Resources  5.50    $219.45
Business & Economic Development 1.25    $49.88
Legislative, Judicial, and Executive    3.71    $148.03
Other

---

..Also, am I using the word "ethical" the correct way in the question? It seems vague how I used it. Would I rather say: is voting on taxes ethically *right* with out being presented the numbers?

Comment: I think the ethical question is when should one vote vs refrain from voting when not understanding the consequences, see [SEP The Ethics and Rationality of Voting](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/voting/). Libertarians use voter ignorance as an argument for small government, see [Voter Ignorance and the Democratic Ideal by Somin](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3007987). The part with specific numbers and  government agencies is off-topic here.

Comment: @conifold the SEP link was perfect, thank you!